# How to convert BitmapImage to StdPicture

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object loaded with an icon, I need to convert that to [StdPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). How do I do that ?

I found tons of examples on how to convert [System.Drawing.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) to [StdPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) but nothing for System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage to [StdPicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267231%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Do I have to first convert it to Winforms Image and then to StdPicture ? Sounds a bit silly to me.

Comment: It is an ancient COM object, the OleCreateIPictureDispIndirect() helper function isn't even documented anymore.  Seeing it used in a program along with BitmapImage is a bit like watching a humans-and-dinosaurs movie, a time anachronism.  Saving the BitmapImage to a file is about as practical as it get.

Comment: @HansPassant I have about 40 images to load at a program Start-up. I have a VS shell project which expects StdPicture objects but I have BitmapImage.

Answer (score -2):

I am assuming stdPicture you mean Bitmap.. So here we go.

```
private Bitmap BitmapImageToBitmap(BitmapImage bitmapImage)
{
    using (MemoryStream os = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
        encoder.Save(os);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(os);

        return new Bitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```